# Can someone please explain?

Tags: google-analytics

Let me start by saying- I am not a very computer literate person.

I have a website on webs.com. I recently upgraded the Clicky Web Analytics. My site doesn't generate much traffic, and I don't pull up the analytics report very often. When I checked it tonight, I received a notification that sent me to this page- 
https://developers.google.com/maps/usagelimits/?utm_referrer=v3

I don't understand why my map view was restricted??? I have only had 394 site visitors in the last 90 days, with 1262 actions.

Is there some problem, or glitch or something? I know I haven't loaded 35,000 maps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its your error i think you need to contact  Clicky Web Analytics.  Its there api that has probably run into an issue with how much they are trying to access google maps.

http://clicky.com/help/#/help/api